# using jquery AJAX with node.js, handling the response from the server

Tags: node.js, jquery, express

this is my first time posting a question on here, I've mostly just been a lurker creeping on other questions, but this is something I've been trying to figure out and for the life of me can't.

Basically what I'm doing is using AJAX from the client side to hop over to the server, run some code that searches an external API which gives me some data, then I need that data to come back to the client. Here is my code... this is all using node.js with express

**Client side**

```
$('#search').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/search",
          dataType: "json"
        }).done (function (data) {
          alert(data);
        });
    });
```

**Server side**

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res){
        factual.get('/t/places',{q:'starbucks'}, function (error, data) {
          console.log(data);
          res.send(data);
        });
  });
```

Now I know that when the #search button is clicked, it does go over to the server and successfully runs that code. But I do not know how to get that data off of the server and back into the client to work with it there.

I found other posts that mention things like, res.send/res.write/res.end, I've tried every form of those to my knowledge and I can never seem to get that data back to the client.

Any tips or possibly better ways to do this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Set the content type header to application/json

Comment: Your code looks just fine. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5382069) you can try: place both files in the same directory, start the server (`node app.js`) and open `http://localhost:3012/`. It doesn't implement `factual.get()`, though, and I would advice you to check `error` to see if any errors occur which might cause problems.

Comment: Thanks to your little test robertklep, you're right, my code is all completely fine, even with the factual.get() implemented. So the issue seems to be somewhere else...

Comment: You must be some kind of wizard robert, because I didn't change anything but it's working now.

And to comment on what lib3d said, you don't need to specify the header type, if you send json, it knows it's json.

Comment: @ribsies if res.send knows it's json if the data is json, what is the difference with res.json ? I'm curious.

Comment: `res.send` will try to guess the content type based on the arguments it is passed. Internally `res.send` calls `this.json` when it deems appropriate. See: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L80-L151

Comment: Also checkout the documents for express here http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json,

res.json turns things into json, so passing in something that is already json has the same effect as using res.send,
res.send can read what the content is

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code server side:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res){
    factual.get('/t/places',{q:'starbucks'}, function (error, data) {
      console.log(data);
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
      res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

It should work. The code client side looks ok.

**Edit:** You can use also :

```
res.json(data);
```